# Big Oh and Little oh notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, order-theory

I have to prove or disprove the following:

$$2n^3 + 5n^2 -3 = o(n^3)$$
$$\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}} = O(1)$$

My attempt at the first question

$$2n^3 + 5n^2 - 3 \leq c |g(x)|$$
$$2n^3+5n^2-3 \leq c |2n^3+5n^3-3n^3|$$
$$2n^3+5n^2-3 \leq c |4n^3|$$
$$2n^3+5n^2-3 \leq 4 |n^3|$$

evaluating when n = 1

$$4 \leq 4$$

when n = 2

$$53 \leq 32$$

hence $$fn \neq o(n^3)$$

My attempt at the second question

$$f_n = \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}} $$

$$ \lim_{n \to -\infty} f_n = \lim_{n \to -\infty} \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}} $$

$$ \lim_{n \to -\infty} f_n = \lim_{n \to -\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}} $$
$$ \lim_{n \to -\infty} f_n =  1 $$

Therefore $$f_n = O(1)$$

can anyone just verify my solution and guide me as to whatever I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $2n^3 + 5n^2 -3 = o(n^3)$ means $ \frac{2n^3+5n^2-3}{n^3} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

But this is fals, since $ \frac{2n^3+5n^2-3}{n^3} \to 2$ as $n \to \infty.$

2. $\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}} = O(1)$ means that the sequence $(\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}})$ is bounded.

This is true, since $0 \le \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}} \le 4$ for all $n.$

Comment: thanks for the confirmation i really appreciate it and the answers you typed @fred

Comment: do you have any ideas about this question @Fred https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655685/newtons-backward-differences