# Newtons Backward Differences

Tags: analysis, derivatives, polynomials, interpolation

I am working on a question with the following data

[image]

x(t) represents the distance traveled by an object at a time t in second.

I was able to determine the interpolating polynomial using Newtons backward differences formula given the polynomial. The question then asked to determine the values of t $\in$ [0,8] for which the velocity of the object exceeds 25 metres per second.

My thinking is if i differentiate the function it would represent the change in distance with respect to time and then solving the equation would allow me to find the maximum and minimum values for the function but how does it help me determine the the range of values which is required? Can anyone guide me to the solution.

Comment: Newton's backward interpolation is supposed to be performed for equidistant nodes. but in you table, the nodes are not equidistant. you better use Lagrange's interpolation formula.

Comment: yes your right the data that was provided was 0, 2 ,4 and 6 that image has an error @ManjoyDas. I used newtons backward differences formula and got the polynomial my question remains the same how to find the values of t for which the object exceeds 25 metres per second @ Manjoy Das

Comment: so after getting the interpolating polynomial, you differentiate it and that would give you the velocity equation. put $ \dfrac{dx}{dt}=25$ and find $ t\in [0,6]$. just check additionally that the object has always a positive acceleration

Comment: oh so after getting the polynomial differentiate the polynomial equate it to 25 and solve for the value x and the value should fall within the range as specified?

Comment: ok thnaks for the help @Manjoy Das

Comment: yes if it has acceleration. but for  negative accelration, it might not be possible.

Comment: its to get the velocity as the t is time and x(t) is distance for the question @ManjoyDas

Comment: i suppose that the object gains acceleration and not a retardation in the given time interval.

Comment: differentiating twice you get the acceleration

Comment: yeah ill just differentiate once to obtain the velocity and differentiate twice if i need the acceleration @Manjoy Das